# Declaring variables in Switch Statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have a function that declares two object from two different classes :

```
 void car (){
   int choice;
   cout << " What type of car ? ";
   cout <<" 1- Fast . 2- Slow.";
   cin >> choice;
   switch(choice)
   {
     case 1: 
       Fast obj1; 
       obj1.print();
       break;
     case 2:
       Slow obj2; 
       obj.print();
       break;
     default: 
       cout << "No type";
   } 
 }
```

The compiler shows error at:

```
switch(choice)
```

This is the error

```
(error: transfer of control bypasses initialization of:
variable "obj1" (declared at line 179)
variable "obj2" (declared at line 181)
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: you forgot `cin>>choice;` before switch. `choice` is not initialized. keep your cases within `{` `}`.

Comment: No , I only forgot it here! sorry :)

Comment: you may want to add a break; to your default: as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error message says, the jump to each switch label passes the initialisation of one or more variables declared inside the switch block, which isn't allowed.

You can fix this by scoping each variable inside a block within the switch block:

```
switch(choice)
{
case 1: 
    {
        Fast obj; 
        obj.print();
        break;
    }
case 2:
    {
        Slow obj; 
        obj.print();
        break;
    }
default: cout << "No type";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use blocks in each case Statement if you want to declare variables there:

```
switch(choice)
{
     case 1: 
     {
         Fast obj1; 
         obj1.print();
     }
     break;

     case 2:
     {
         Slow obj2; 
         obj.print();
     }
    break;

    default: 
        cout << "No type";
}
```